# skipping through foreach with multiple conditions

Tags: php

I'm trying to get my foreach to skip certain children in the xml based on one of the childrens values. The first code works for skipping just 1 but I want to skip a lot. The second code won't skip any of them.

```
<?php
$gamespage = simplexml_load_file("http://gamepage.com/games?xml=1");
    foreach($gamespage->games->game as $game)
    {
    $gid = $game->appID;
    if ($gid != 65920) { 
} }
```

second code (not skipping any):

```
<?php
$gamespage = simplexml_load_file("http://gamepage.com/games?xml=1");
    foreach($gamespage->games->game as $game)
    {
    $gid = $game->appID;
    if ($gid != 65920 || $gid != 40940 || $gid != 50110 || $gid != 8990) {
} }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `&&` instead of `||`

Or even better

```
if (!in_array($gid, array(65920, 40940, ...)))
```